# Update (not set) Android Firebase child data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Please be patient with me, I am still learning Java and there is a lot I do not yet know.

By following an online tutorial I have created a simple logging in/registering app which connects to Firebase. However, I would now like to update some of the data in the database without altering the other data. For example, for the logged in user, the code below allows then to enter their name and address. But what about if on another activity I wanted them to be able to add their age. Using set() will overwrite all other date, but I can't figure out how to use update().

I have searched this forum and elsewhere but don't really understand the answers enough to apply them to my situation. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

```
    private void saveUserInformation(){

    String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString().trim();

    UserInformation userInformation = new UserInformation(name, address);
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userInformation);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Information Saved...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and

```
public class UserInformation {

public String name;
public String address;

public UserInformation(String name, String address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add another info (child) to your user (e.g age) try this:

```
databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).child("age").setValue(22);
```

Explanation here, taken from Firebase tutorial:

[image: Screenshot from reference]

Comment: Thank you, I will try this later. If I add this separately (after) the other information, won't it remove the name and address? I thought I had to use update(), not set(),,,

Comment: @Adrian after creating user with name and address you get JSON tree with main child being `userId` and two subchildren `name` and `address`. Now if you want to add more data to your `userId` child you need to create a new subchild for example `age`. You do that the way I described and no data is being removed or replaced. The only way you would remove `name` and `address` is if you created a new Class that has only `age` field and set it like this `databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(objectWithAge);` About `update()` - I believe you can do it by creating new HashMap with age in it.

Comment: TomiQrsd - thank you so much, really easy to understand and works perfectly. Thanks for providing the exact code plus the line from the Firebase tutorial, it will help me understand and translate other Firebase examples to fit my project. Cheers pal